# Webpack: Module build failed with jade-loader

Tags: webpack

This is likely a config issue, but I'm new to Webpack and haven't been able to figure it out after a few days. I'd appreciate some help!

**Packages**

- webpack 1.9.8
- jade-loader 0.7.1
- jade 1.9.2

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  // ...
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".json", ".js", ".jade" ],
    root: [ path.join(__dirname, 'src/js'), path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules') ],
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader" },
      { test: /modernizr/, loader: "imports?this=>window!exports?window.Modernizr" },
      { text: /\.jade$/, loader: "jade-loader" }
    ]
  }
  // ...
};
```

With a completely empty entry file, I get the following error when trying to run webpack.

```
ERROR in ./~/jade/lib/runtime.js
Module build failed: Error: unexpected token "indent"
    at MyParser.Parser.parseExpr (/Users/name/project/code/assets/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:252:15)
    at MyParser.Parser.parse (/Users/name/project/code/assets/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:122:25)
    at parse (/Users/name/project/code/assets/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:104:21)
    at Object.exports.compileClientWithDependenciesTracked (/Users/name/project/code/assets/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:256:16)
    at Object.exports.compileClient (/Users/name/project/code/assets/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:289:18)
    at run (/Users/name/project/code/assets/node_modules/jade-loader/index.js:170:24)
    at Object.module.exports (/Users/name/project/code/assets/node_modules/jade-loader/index.js:167:2)
 @ ./entry.js 1:11-85
```

If I actually require a jade file within entry.js, I get a different error:

```
ERROR in ./entry.js
Module build failed: Error: unexpected text ;
var
    at Object.Lexer.fail (/Users/name/project/code/assets/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:871:11)
    at Object.Lexer.next (/Users/name/project/code/assets/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:930:15)
    at Object.Lexer.lookahead (/Users/name/project/code/assets/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:113:46)
    at MyParser.Parser.lookahead (/Users/name/project/code/assets/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:102:23)
    at MyParser.Parser.peek (/Users/name/project/code/assets/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:79:17)
    at MyParser.Parser.tag (/Users/name/project/code/assets/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:752:22)
    at MyParser.Parser.parseTag (/Users/name/project/code/assets/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:738:17)
    at MyParser.Parser.parseExpr (/Users/name/project/code/assets/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:211:21)
    at MyParser.Parser.parse (/Users/name/project/code/assets/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:122:25)
    at parse (/Users/name/project/code/assets/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:104:21)
```

However, if I comment out the jade loader line in `webpack.config.js` and require the jade file with the inline syntax `require('jade!template.jade')` -- everything works okay.

Any idea what's up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your webpack config contains a typo.

```
  { text: /\.jade$/, loader: "jade-loader" }
```

should be

```
  { test: /\.jade$/, loader: "jade-loader" }
      ^ x -> s
```